# Differences between swap part in top command vs swap -l command

Tags: memory, solaris, swap, top

I have a system running with 256Gb RAM. My swap space is getting exhausted due to some process. So as a diagnostics, we put a crontab to monitor the usage and space. This is where I am confused.

The top Command shows below o/p:

```
Memory: 256G phys mem, 24G free mem, 20G total swap, 12G free swap
```

Whereas, the swap command shows the following.

```
swap -s
total: 207467584k bytes allocated + 5100648k reserved = 212568232k used, 46298252k available
```

I am unable to dissect or co-relate the two outputs. The first one says, 20G whereas the second one says 212G. I am confused on how to read the outputs. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the [swap manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19109-01/tsolaris8/817-0880/6mglau86h/index.html) for Solaris and it looks like `swap -s` is *not* intended to give you the information you're looking for. This command and this option describe your swap storage configuration, not the actual swap use:

*"These numbers include swap space from all configured swap areas as listed by the -l option, as well swap space in the form of **physical memory**".*

Looks like Solaris treats RAM as a swap backing store which means that your `top` output is what you should be paying attention to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. @Artem.